# Transformar DD/MM/YY em timestamp PHP

Tags: php, sql

Preciso que o usuário informe uma data e essa data seja enviada ao banco de dados como timestamp, exemplo

Inserir: **25/12/17** no campo

Quero que chegue ao banco de dados como **1514160000** que significa "Mon, 25 Dec 2017 00:00:00 GMT"

Não tentei nada, porque não sei o que e como cada função funciona no PHP

Agradeço qualquer dica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php

```
$timestamp = strtotime('12/25/17');
```

Perceba que eu inverti a posição do dia e mês, é o padrão norte americano invertido de ser. E para fazer isso:

```
$data = '25/12/17';
$dataParcial = explode('/', $data);
$data =  $dataParcial[1] . '/' . $dataParcial[0] . '/' . $dataParcial[2];
$timestamp = strtotime($data);
```

Como @GabrielHeming apontou nos comentários, strtotime vai reconhecer uma data no formato m/d/y na documentação da função você poderá verificar diversos outros formatos possíveis!

Comment: A sua resposta está com o formato correto (m/d/y), mas trará um resultado inesperado para o formato (d/m/y) que o AP possui.

Comment: Obrigado por pontuar @GabrielHeming. Já estava preparando a edição :)

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado irmão

Answer (score 2):

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','20/10/2017');

$timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Dessa maneira, você pode criar um objeto DateTime, a partir de qualquer formato.
https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [strtotime()](http://php.net/function.strtotime), exemplo:

```
$timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '08/11/2017'));
```

Observando os [Formatos de Data e Hora Suportados](http://php.net/datetime.formats)

---

Utilizando [strptime()](http://www.php.net/strptime)

```
$a = strptime('08/11/2017', '%d/%m/%Y');
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon']+1, $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year']+1900);
```